# C# await Task.Run is not awaited

Tags: c#, async-await

I have some long running background calculation task

```
private async void StartButton_onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = Task.Run(() => Calculate(cts.Token));
    tasks.Add(task);
    await task;
    tasks.Remove(task);
    cts = null;
}
```

The task can be cancelled when user clicks on `Cancel` button and should be automatically cancelled when user calls some other activity, let's say presses `Change` button to open a dialog to change calculation parameters.

In order to aviod writing the cancelation code twice for the two operations I moved it to a separate method

```
public async void CancelAsync()
{
    if (cts != null && !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

and call it from the buttons click event

```
private async void CancelButton_onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => CancelAsync());
}

private async void ChangeButton_onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => CancelAsync());
    OpenDialog();
}
```

The issue is that the `OpenDialog()` method is called **before** `CancelAsync()` runs to compeletion.

What am I dong wrong here please?

Comment: You should not use `async void` unless you're writing an event handler. CancelAsync is not an event handler. It should return a Task.

Comment: `using (cts = new CancellationTokenSource()) {...}` since `CancellationTokenSource` implements `IDisposable`

Comment: Doesn't it return a task when called within Task.Run wrapper?

Comment: mason, you're right. changing void to Task solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove `Task.Run`, does it freeze the UI thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are calling CancelAsync() from a lambda that is not async nor awaited, the lambda will complete before the `CancelAsync()` method returns. In order to make it work as intended use either

```
public async Task CancelAsync()
{
    if (cts != null && !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}

await CancelAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the use of `Task.Run`, which is meant to run some synchronous code on the thread pool and allow you to await the result of that.  However, you are passing asynchronous code to `Task.Run` as if it is synchronous code, so Task.Run thinks the work is done as soon as the CancelAsync() returns a task, not when it completes its task.

Try this instead:

```
private async void ChangeButton_onClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await CancelAsync();
    OpenDialog();
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to return a `task` to await it ?